# How to parallelize crossprod for computing co-occurrence matrix?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cross-product

I'm using the R's base `crossprod` function to compute word co-occurrences as shown below:

```
t <- tibble(doc=c(rep('d1', 3), rep('d2', 2), rep('d3', 2)), 
            term=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c'))
table(t[1:2])
    term
doc  a b c
  d1 1 1 1
  d2 0 1 1
  d3 1 0 1

CP <- crossprod(table(t[1:2]))
diag(CP) <- 0
CP
    term
term a b c
   a 0 1 2
   b 1 0 2
   c 2 2 0
```

My actual `t` has 1'245'332 rows and `crossprod` takes about ~15m to compute. btw I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and have all the big guns: MKL latest, CUDA, MAGMA and the fastest CUDA tensor cores.

Comment: `t` is a predefined function (transpose). Try not to overwrite them

Comment: Is R linked to parallel MKL?